# operation rejected by operating system when using vue-ctl to create project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I encountered this problem while using creating project with Vue-CLI.

Has anyone encountered this problem ?

---

Win10 - CMD (administrator rights)

@vue-cli 4.5.4

npm 6.14.6

---

I execute :

```
vue create font_end3
```

```
s: sill extract rxjs@^6.6.0 extracted to D:\Programing\MeowalienWeb\playground\go\font_end3\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-60d4e2de (39928ms) 

extract: WARN tarball tarball data for rxjs@^5.0.0-beta.11 (sha1-b6YbinfD15PbrycL7i9D9lLXQcw=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

Then ...

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\Programing\MeowalienWeb\playground\go\font_end3\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-7636eb31\bundles\Rx.js
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Programing\MeowalienWeb\playground\go\font_end3\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-7636eb31\bundles\Rx.js'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Programing\MeowalienWeb\playground\go\font_end3\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-7636eb31\bundles\Rx.js'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Programing\MeowalienWeb\playground\go\font_end3\node_modules\.staging\rxjs-7636eb31\bundles\Rx.js'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\Programing\\MeowalienWeb\\playground\\go\\font_end3\\node_modules\\.staging\\rxjs-7636eb31\\bundles\\Rx.js'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Programing\\MeowalienWeb\\playground\\go\\font_end3\\node_modules\\.staging\\rxjs-7636eb31\\bundles\\Rx.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'font_end3'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\喵星人\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-21T09_42_35_452Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start terminal, vs code or webstorm (run as administrator). Just to be admin in system isn't enough.
Was helpful for me.